# Apple TV+ (the subscription) - how can I tell what it actually offers?

Tags: appletv

I recently activated my one year subscription to Apple TV, after buying a phone.

However, I find it very challenging to tell what it actually delivers.  Not a big deal while it's free, but certainly makes it unlikely I'll renew at $5/mo or so.

- Sicario, the movie, shows up.  Great, except that I can rent or buy it.  So, not included with Apple TV.
- Game of Thrones.  Great, except that it seems like Apple TV is helpfully aggregating it to itself from my paid-for Crave (HBO's distributor in Canada) subscription.  Sure enough, it sends me to the Crave app and replaces what Crave was previously playing.
- Greyhound (Tom Hanks) WW2 movie.  This one seems to be on the level and actually part of the channel, but nothing really differentiates it from Game of Thrones, except for a small icon bottom right.

And so on.  How do I see what a subscription actually buys me?  And how, when I search, do I avoid extra-fee listings like Sicario?

Comment: Open the AppleTV App and then find the AppleTV+ logo/button and tap/click on that. That will give you the shows included with AppleTV. Everything else is available (often) with an additional subscription sold through the AppleTV app.

Comment: @SteveChambers - bottom left **Watch Now** from home, followed by scrolling about midway through the new page, find **Available Apple TV Channels** but then click only on the leftmost AppleTV+ round channel button?  Wow, it's almost as if they wanted to inflate the impression of more content.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I browse TV+ content is by opening the TV app on iPad and look for the channels. Tap on it, then you can see all the major shows. Also, on each show in the app, look for the service in the text as well as the badging in the lower right corner.

[image: image of one show on Apple TV Plus]

Of course the free episodes can and will change, so I wouldn’t count on things that are free today being so in a month or vice-versa. If you prefer web access: https://tv.apple.com lets you browse and watch off device (AppleTV, iPhone, iPad, etc..) in a native app.

Since the native apps show all channels, not everything is included nor is everything in the app advertisement free, however what you pay for from the + is commercial free, downloadable, playable for the duration of the subscription whether it’s subsidized or paid in cash / store credit.